# JavaScript Callback function Problem

Tags: javascript

Please see my code below:

```
        var callback = function(popup_window) {
            popup_window.close();
           //some more codes here
        };
        var prepare = function(cb) {
            popup_window = window.open("my_url");
            this.cb(popup_window);
        };
        function refresh(){
            prepare(callback);
        };
```

How can I pass the **popup_window** variable to the callback function ?

Comment: You already are passing popup_window to the callback in your code `this.cb(popup_window);`. What do you really mean? Note: why `this.cb()`? I wouldn't expect that to work, while `cb()` should work.

Comment: what do u actually want to do?

Comment: I am trying to pass popup_window but this actually not passed to callback function because my window did not closed. I am trying to close the opened window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var prepare = function(cb) {
        var popup_window = window.open("my_url");
        cb(popup_window);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `this.cb(popup_window);` to `cb(popup_window);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.cb()` with `cb()`